# How Do I Limit A Cart Only To The Same Seller? (PHP)

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I am currently doing a feature where my Add To Cart Feature is only allowed for the same Seller due to the intentional limitation of my website and instruction from my lecturer, where I want to have my add to cart feature only allows the User/Buyer to add bicycles only from the same Seller.

If they are from a different Seller, a simple alert box will appear to inform them that they cannot purchase bicycles from a different Seller and the bicycles that they try to add will not be added into the cart.

```
  <form method='POST' action='cart.php?action=addCart&BicycleID=<?php echo $row["BicycleID"]; ?>'>
                                         <p style="color:black;float:center;margin-top:5px;">Quantity: <input type='number' name='gadget_quantity' value='0' style="width:20%;color:black;" min="1" max="5"></p>
                                        
                                 <?php
                                
                                $colors=explode("," , $row['BicycleColor']);
                                $colors = array_diff($colors, array(""));
                                    
                                ?>
                                 
                                    <select name="visible_color" style="width:200px;margin-bottom:10px;">
                                     
                                    <?php
                                            foreach($colors as $color):
                                            $color = trim($color);
                                            echo '<option value="'.$color.'">'.$color.'</option>'; //close your tags!!
                                            endforeach;
                                    ?>
                                     
                                   </select>
                                        
                                        <button  name='addCart' class="btn btn-default add-to-cart" style="margin-top:2px;"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add To Cart</button>
                                    
                                    <input type='hidden' name='hidden_id' value="<?php echo $row["BicycleID"];?>">    
                                    <input type='hidden' name='hidden_name' value="<?php echo $row["BicycleName"];?>">  
                                    <input type='hidden' name='hidden_price' value="<?php echo $row["BicyclePrice"];?>">
                                    <input type='hidden' name='hidden_image' value="<?php echo $row["BicycleImage"];?>">
                                    <input type='hidden' name='hidden_seller' value="<?php echo $row["AccountUsername"];?>">
                                    <input type='hidden' name='hidden_bank' value="<?php echo $row["SellerBank"];?>">    
 </form>
```

I just need a solution that will check every time a bicycle is added into the cart that checks whether the Seller that was added as the first one into the cart does not allow the next to be from a different Seller unless the User/Buyer clears the cart with a remove all button then a different Seller can be chosen but the rule still applies that only the Same Seller from the first bicycle that is added to the cart is allowed to be added. The code below is on the cart page where the bicycles that are added will be displayed here. Hope this is clear enough, please let me know.

```
<?php 
include('dbconnect.php');

if (isset($_POST["addCart"])){
    if (isset($_SESSION["cart"][0])){
        $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["cart"],"BicycleID");
        if (!in_array($_GET["BicycleID"],$item_array_id)){
            $count = count($_SESSION["cart"]);
            $item_array = array(
                'BicycleID' => $_POST["hidden_id"],
                'BicycleName' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                'BicyclePrice' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                'BicycleImage' => $_POST["hidden_image"],
                'BicycleColor' => $_POST["visible_color"],
                'AccountUsername' => $_POST["hidden_seller"],
                'SellerBank' => $_POST["hidden_bank"],
                'gadget_quantity' => $_POST["gadget_quantity"],
            );
            $_SESSION["cart"][$count] = $item_array;
            echo '<script>window.location="cart.php"</script>';           
        
         }
        else{
            echo '<script>alert("Product is already Added to Cart")</script>';
            echo '<script>window.location="cart.php"</script>';
        }
    }
    else{
        $item_array = array(
            'BicycleID' => $_POST["hidden_id"],
            'BicycleName' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
            'BicyclePrice' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
            'BicycleImage' => $_POST["hidden_image"],
            'BicycleColor' => $_POST["visible_color"],
            'AccountUsername' => $_POST["hidden_seller"],
            'SellerBank' => $_POST["hidden_bank"],
            'gadget_quantity' => $_POST["gadget_quantity"],
        );
        $_SESSION["cart"][0] = $item_array;
    }
}

if (isset($_GET["action"])){
    if ($_GET["action"] == "empty"){
       unset($_SESSION["cart"]);
    }
    
}  
if (isset($_GET["action"])){
    if ($_GET["action"] == "delete"){
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $keys => $value){
            if ($value["BicycleID"] == $_GET["BicycleID"]){
                unset($_SESSION["cart"][$keys]);
                echo '<script>alert("Bicycle has been Removed")</script>';
                echo '<script>window.location="cart.php"</script>';
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like all you need is just a condition -> `$_POST["hidden_seller"] == $_SESSION["cart"][0]['hidden_seller']`

```
<?php 
include('dbconnect.php');

if (isset($_POST["addCart"])){
    if (isset($_SESSION["cart"][0])){
        $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["cart"],"BicycleID");
        if (!in_array($_GET["BicycleID"],$item_array_id)){
            if($_POST["hidden_seller"] == $_SESSION["cart"][0]['hidden_seller']){

                $count = count($_SESSION["cart"]);
                $item_array = array(
                    'BicycleID' => $_POST["hidden_id"],
                    'BicycleName' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
                    'BicyclePrice' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
                    'BicycleImage' => $_POST["hidden_image"],
                    'BicycleColor' => $_POST["visible_color"],
                    'AccountUsername' => $_POST["hidden_seller"],
                    'SellerBank' => $_POST["hidden_bank"],
                    'gadget_quantity' => $_POST["gadget_quantity"],
                );
                $_SESSION["cart"][$count] = $item_array;
                echo '<script>window.location="cart.php"</script>';           
            }else{
                echo '<script>alert(" {message error } ")</script>';
                echo '<script>window.location="cart.php"</script>';

            }
         }
        else{
            echo '<script>alert("Product is already Added to Cart")</script>';
            echo '<script>window.location="cart.php"</script>';
        }
    }
    else{
        $item_array = array(
            'BicycleID' => $_POST["hidden_id"],
            'BicycleName' => $_POST["hidden_name"],
            'BicyclePrice' => $_POST["hidden_price"],
            'BicycleImage' => $_POST["hidden_image"],
            'BicycleColor' => $_POST["visible_color"],
            'AccountUsername' => $_POST["hidden_seller"],
            'SellerBank' => $_POST["hidden_bank"],
            'gadget_quantity' => $_POST["gadget_quantity"],
        );
        $_SESSION["cart"][0] = $item_array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the good response, i tried to use the first method and technically it does work but i cant add for the same seller as well. However, the alternative cleaner method that you have provided seems a lot better to me and I want to implement this one. Everything seems to be fine for the new method but I am getting these errors that i will sent in another comment.

Comment: Warning: Undefined array key "cart" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cycle Haven\cart.php on line 28

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: array_column(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cycle Haven\cart.php:28 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Cycle Haven\cart.php(28): array_column(NULL, 'BicycleID') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Cycle Haven\cart.php(41): check_item_existe() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Cycle Haven\cart.php(56): add_cart() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cycle Haven\cart.php on line 28

Comment: @kingxtable seems like `$_SESSION["cart"][0]` existe and was is define as `NULL`
( like an action empty cart or somewhere have `$_SESSION["cart"][0] = NULL` )

Comment: Update: I've tried checking everything and it seems to run with no problems now but i just cant seem to add more than one bicycle regardless of seller

Comment: @kingxtable no alert and items add in cart ?

Comment: Actually I looked back into the code after a while i noticed that the one that i said could run and was fine was the first code not the new one, the new one still has the same error I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @kingxtable i remove the new one temporary before test complet

Comment: items do add to cart, but only for the first time. alerts come out as well but they come out every time regardless of seller. Even if its the same seller, which is a problem that I tried to fix these past 2 days but nothing seems to work. Now the only thing left is to make the alert only work on a different seller and allows bicycles from the same seller to be added.